# Is this spring tutorial out of date?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

To learn spring MVC im using this tutorial - http://static.springsource.org/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/index.html

It refers to spring2.5 wheras the current release is 3.1. It references jar files that are no longer available in the most recent release of spring (spring.jar , spring-webmvc.jar, commons-logging.jar). Should I search for a tutorial that is related to the most recent version of spring or are there no major changes between each versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes**, it is out-of-date. They are using Ant, JUnit 3.x and XML configuration style without any help of annotations like `@Controller`, not to mention `@Bean`.

Spring is known to have a perfect history of backward compatibility, which means any Spring tutorial found on the web will work on any newer version. However you should look for something more up-to-date.

Answer (score 2):

It's slightly out-of-date. There are more conveniences; personally I think the [MVC reference docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html) are more useful anyway, along with the many 3.x tutorials.

Just FYI, the current release is 3.1.

Comment: According to http://www.springsource.com/download/community?project=Spring%20Framework the current stable release is 3.0. 3.1.x are RC & M releases

Comment: @user470184 According to the [Spring framework home page](http://www.springsource.org/spring-framework) it's 3.1. Because it's 3.1. And it was [blogged about a week ago](http://blog.springsource.org/2011/12/13/spring-framework-3-1-goes-ga/).